# localStorage не меняет значение по клику

Tags: javascript, jquery, localstorage

Мне нужно по клику изменить значение, такой код не работает

```
var watchedBtn = localStorage.getItem('watched')
btn.on('click', function(){ 
  if(watchedBtn == 1) {
    localStorage.setItem('watched', 0);
    console.log(watchedBtn) // each click = 1
  } else {
    localStorage.setItem('watched', 1);
    console.log(watchedBtn) // each click = 0
  }
});
```

Почему значение не меняется каждый раз при клике?

---

```
if(localStorage.getItem('watched') == 1) {
```

Вместо

```
if(watchedBtn == 1) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Значение в `localStorage` никак не связано со значение переменной.

Поэтому, для того, чтобы после `localStorage.setItem('watched', 1);` значение `watchedBtn` обновилось, его нужно либо самому изменить: `watchedBtn = 1` либо заново загрузить из `localStorage`.